# Getting the measurements for stretching

Tags: lisp, autocad, stretch, autocad-plugin, autolisp

I am creating an algorithm to help me expand boxes to the correct size, as such:

[image: inteded result]

I made a code that asks two points that should be the new depth and measures them. Then subtracts to the original depth of the block (`0.51`) and then asks the side to stretch.

```
(defun mystretchh ( dis / pt1 pt2 sel )
    (while
        (and
            (setq pt1 (getpoint "\nFirst point of selection window: "))
            (setq pt2 (getcorner pt1 "\nSecond point of selection window: "))
            (not (setq sel (ssget "_C" pt1 pt2)))
        )
        (princ "\nNo objects where found in the selection window.")
    )
    (if sel
        (progn
            (command "_.stretch" sel "" "_non" '(0 0) "_non" (list dis 0))
            t
        )
    )
)
(defun c:test (/ a x c p)
;ungroup
(command "pickstyle" 0)
;variables
(initget (+ 1 2 4))
(setq p (getpoint "\nSelect first point: "))
(setq c (getpoint "\nSelect second point: "))
(command "_.dist" p c)
(setq x (rtos (getvar 'distance) 2 3))


    ;calculate distance to stretch
    (setq a (- x 0.51))


    ;stretch
    (mystretchh a)

    ;regroup
    (command "pickstyle" 1)
    (print "Module modified.")
    (princ)
)
```

I have two problems:

1. The stretch is working backwards, I tried using negative values to no avail.
2. It reports a syntax error, but I cannot find it.

I haven't touched AutoLISP for half a year - maybe some of you can find the problems in a blink of an eye.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the distance between two points using the standard [`distance`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-62F2AA98-1CE4-4E31-A2B7-E2C49A92E38F) function, rather than calling the [`DIST`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-A72EADC7-EF79-463C-B4F1-862C6139B004) command and then retrieving the value of the [`DISTANCE`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-F55E2C37-515A-4560-B3BC-C2EE09A7F60D) system variable.

Hence, this:

```
(command "_.dist" p c)
(setq x (rtos (getvar 'distance) 2 3))
```

Can become:

```
(setq x (rtos (distance p c) 2 3))
```

However, you are receiving a syntax error because you have converted the distance to a string using [`rtos`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-D03ABBC2-939A-44DB-8C93-FC63B64DE4A2), and then you are attempting to perform arithmetic on the string here:

```
(setq a (- x 0.51))
```

There is no need to convert the distance to a string, and so these expressions can become:

```
(setq a (- (distance p c) 0.51))
```

You may also want to check whether `(distance p c)` is greater than `0.51` before performing this subtraction to avoid unexpected results.

To determine the appropriate direction, since your current code can only stretch along the x-axis, you'll need to check whether or not the x-coordinate of point `p` is greater than that of point `c`.